# J-link debugger couldn't connect to target, VTref is 0.000V

Tags: debugging, segger-jlink

I am trying to connect my PC to the following board: https://nxp.gitbook.io/nxp-cup/dfrobot-chassis-developer-guide/development-tools/arc-board-development

I am using NXPXpresso to do this, ,and have tried to use a J-link edu mini debugger to flash and debug the program I am trying to load. I have connected the debugger to the board and also a battery to the board, and the board light's up but when i submit the program, the j link commander says cannot connect to target, VTref is 0.000V, even though I have connected a battery. Please help.

I tried to debug and expected J-link to find the board, but was unsuccesful.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? If yes: Did you measure the voltage between pin 1 and pin 3 of the debug connector at the eval board? It should be 3.3V.

Comment: I don't have a multimeter :\, anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using a J-Link EDU Mini?
The J-Link EDU Mini only supports 3.3V targets [1][2] and therefore should (afaik) always show 3.3 V VTref, even if nothing is connected.

[1] https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/model-overview/ ("Supported target voltage") 
[2] https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu-mini/ ("Target interface voltage")